# Remove new line character by checking the expression, using sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, aix

Have to write a script which updates the file in this way.

raw file:

```
<?blah blah blah?>
<pen>
<?pineapple?>
<apple>
<pen>
```

Final file:

```
<?blah blah blah?><pen>
<?pineapple?><apple><pen>
```

Where ever in the file if the new line charter is not followed by

```
<?
```

We have to remove the newline in order to append it at the end of previous line.

Also it will be really helpful if you explain how your sed works.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed. Adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 'chomp; substr $_, 0, 0, "\n" if $. > 1 && /^<\?/'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, printing each line after changes
- [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) removes the final newline
- [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) with 4 arguments modifies the input string, here it prepends newline if it's not the first line (`$.` is the input line number) and the line starts with `<?`.

Comment: @MaanooAk: Right tool for the job etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sed solution:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\(<[^?]\)/\1/g' file > newfile
```

The basic idea is to replace every

`\n` followed by `<` **not** followed by `?`

with what you matched except the `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are happy with a solution that puts every `<?` at the start of a line, you can combine `tr` with `sed`.

```
tr -d '\n' < inputfile| sed 's/<?/\n&/g;$s/$/\n/'
```

Explanation:
I use `tr ... < inputfile` and not `cat inputfile | tr ...` avoiding an additional `cat`call.
The `sed` command has 2 parts.
In `s/<?/\n&/g` it will insert a newline and with `&` it will insert the matched string (in this case always `<?`, so it will only save one character).
With `$s/$/\n/` a newline is appended at the end of the last line.

EDIT: When you only want newlines before `<?` when you had them already,
you can use `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^<\?/ {print} {printf("%s",$0)} END {print}'
```

Explanation:
Consider the newline as the start of the line, not the end. Then your question transposes into "write a newline when the line starts with `<?`. You must escape the `?` and use `^` for the start of the line.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^<\?/ {print}'
```

Next print the line you read without a newline character.
And you want a newline at the end.